# How to build subscription application with own instance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, digital-ocean

*My question title may not appropriate as I am not so aware of how to call it. I will appreciate it if anyone can edit to fits the query.*

I am planning to build a web application where users will subscribe. For instance, CRM or Project management application. I want to have a separate instance and database with a custom domain for enterprise subscribers, and I may have a common database or instance for non-enterprise subscribers. The subscription will be handled through a marketing website, where all subscribers will checkout and have their own account.

- Marketing website to subscribe
- Application instance / website/ database / etc

Once the subscription period is over and it is not renewed, they will lose access. If they do not renew/reactivate for x time, the instance will destroy itself.

*I am quite confident with `PHP` and `MySQL,` have some knowledge of **AWS** and **Digital Ocean**. I am planning to use **Laravel** for serverside. However, I am open to other languages as well, such as python.`*

> Can anyone help me to learn the best approach for the system I want to
> make. Pros and Cons and things to be considered? Also, approach to make a mobile application for the subscriber where they can access their own instance.

Comment: Basically the thing you're talking about is Software As A Service (SAAS or SaaS), if that helps your research.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, that is the word I couldn't recall in my mind :P Thanks a lot. It will help.

Comment: You may want to check "multi-tenancy" applications as well.

Comment: @mirza Thanks a lot for the input. I am learning the right term that helps me to look helpful for the right things.